# Suddenly "No soundcards found"

Tags: 14.04, sound, soundcard, devices

After having worked properly for a month, my sound card went missing.
It was probably after I forced a restart (laptop frozen).

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS on a laptop with a pretty basic Sound Card  Intel 2 Channel High Definition Audio.

```
aplay -l
```

gives

```
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...

lsmod | grep snd
```

gives nothing.

I tried many solutions but none seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the card integrated?

Comment: Does the card still work when you boot into another OS (live OS for example) ?

Comment: @Alexiy yes it is!

Comment: @potAito I don't have any other OS on the laptop, should try with something from usb or cd?

Comment: As nothing detects the card, I think it is not supported or is damaged.

Comment: @AndreaPisauro If you have one handy, I would try a live system from USB you can use ubuntu for that. Then at least you can rule out a misconfiguration in your current OS.

Comment: @Alexiy Why unsupported? Andrea says it did work for months.

Comment: @potAito Right. Then can it be damaged?

Comment: @Alexiy Would be possible, that's why I suggest to boot another OS. If the card is not working there as well, then there is a hardware problem for sure.

Comment: so I tried from a live OS and still no sound card detected. So I restarted with the normal OS and the computer froze. I forced a restart and once I logged in the sound card was finally recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out Ubuntu's own sound card issues page, it has helped me a few times in the past and gives you simple instructions on testing and re-enabling sound cards: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

Comment: So it is a helpful checklist, I arrived until point 6 where
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
gives nothing

In the bios I found no option to enable the sound card. 
Still don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by forcing a restart after the computer had frozen. Still not sure whether it's a hardware or software issue or a combination of the two.